# Display 500+ character field from SAP transparent table

Tags: abap, sap-basis, sap-data-dictionary

As it commonly known, it is not recommended by SAP to use 255+ character fields in transparent tables. One should use several 255 fields instead, wrap text in LCHR, LRAW or STRING, or use SO10 text etc.

However, while maintaining legacy (and ugly) developments, such problem often arises: how to view what is stored in `char500` or `char1000` field in database?
The real life scenario:

1. we have a development where some structure written and read from `char1000` field in transparent table
2. we know field structure and parsing the field through `CL_ABAP_CONTAINER_UTILITIES=>FILL_CONTAINER_C` or `SO_STRUCT_TO_CHAR` goes fine, all fields are put wonderfully
3. displaying the fields via SE11/SE16/SE16n gives nothing as the field is truncated to 255, and to 132 in debugger, AFAIR.

Is there any **standard** tool, transaction or FM we can use to display such long field?

Comment: I'm curious to know where it is mentioned that SAP does not recommend a field of more than 255 characters in transparent tables? It's more a matter of database systems, not SAP.

Comment: Yep, this info is a bit outdated. In older releases it was impossible to save 255+ char fields to DB, then the limit was increased to 1333. However, up to now there are limitations while using these fields in a primary key or displaying them in a smartform or ALV. Technically it is possible, but it is a pain to read/show them from DB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the DBA cockpit (ST04), there is a SQL command line, where you can enter directly the "native" SQL commands and display the result as an ALV view. With a substring function, you can split a field into several sections (expl: `select substr(sql_text,1,100) s1, substr(sql_text,101,100) s2, substr(sql_text,201,100) s3, substr(sql_text,301,100) s4 from dba_hist_sqltext where sql_id = '0cuyjatkcmjf0'`). PS: every ALV cell is 128 characters maximum.

Not sure whether this tool is available for all supported database softwares.

There is also an equivalent program named RSDU_EXEC_SQL (in all ABAP-based systems?)

Unfortunately, they won't work for ersatz of tables by SAP (clustered tables and so on) as they can be queried only with ABAP "Open SQL".

Comment: Well, in my 7.00 system I have SQL command window. [Here is](https://imgur.com/AZhi5k0) how my DBACOCKPIT looks like, no nodes in Performance folder. What should I do then?

Comment: It's not always in the Performance folder, it depends on the underlying database and on the release of ABAP. For instance, in ABAP 7.31, for a SAPDB system, it's in the folder Diagnostics, menu "SELECT Editor". Anyway, I guess that it's possible that in your system, you don't have any SQL command line, so in that case I don't see any solution other than creating your own tool (this doesn't answer your question then).

Comment: Tool `RSDU_EXEC_SQL` is cool, but it weirdly throws 'YOU ARE NOT AUTHORIZED TO USE THIS TOOL', though SU53 gives nothing and shows that all authorization checks are passed. Also I tried your query on several backend systems (MSSQL and ORACLE) and everywhere it throws that [table doesn't exist](https://imgur.com/Vp9lJBb).

Comment: Well, I adapted your query for MSSQL and can confirm that it's functional: `select substring(SERVICE_URL,1,100) AS s1, substring(SERVICE_URL,101,100) AS s2, substring(SERVICE_URL,202,100) AS s3, substring(SERVICE_URL,303,100) AS s4
from sid.VBCC_SERV_URL
where LEN(sid.VBCC_SERV_URL) > 250`. However, columns are filled awkward, look at [these question marks](https://imgur.com/v29cznf) wrapping the text. Why is so?

Comment: DBA_HIST_SQLTEXT is an Oracle table. I guess it used to exist for years, in many Oracle releases. Write a SQL statement with a table which exists in your system.

Comment: Probably that, with MSSQL, substring returns `????` when you query more characters than the column contains for the given row. Do the same with len(sid.VBCC_SERV_URL) >= 400, and you won't get `????` because you query only the first 400 characters.

Comment: Now it is showed fine, seems to be some temp bug. Interesting, where did you find the option to output query results as ALV. I don't see such option on my system

Comment: In ST04, an ALV is shown at least with ABAP 740/Oracle, ABAP 731/SAPDB. RSDU_EXEC_SQL displays data using an ABAP list, it doesn't use ALV.

Comment: `with ABAP 740/Oracle`, interesting. Didn't now it's database-dependent. I have 7.40 but MSSQL and I have no such option. It should be the work of frontend, not backend, no?

Comment: Database "cockpits" are different programs. ST04 starts different transactions: for instance, ORA_PERF for Oracle, ST04_MSS for MSSQL, DB50 for SAPDB... Edit: not sure for operating system cockpits, but at least a few tools need to be different because they show information from the operating system, and the way 2 operating systems works can be of "very" different natures.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an ERP system to you hand check transaction PP01 out with infotype 1002. Basically They store text in table HRP1002 and HRT1002 and create a special view with an text editor. It looks like this: http://www.sapfunctional.com/HCM/Positions/Page1.13.jpg

 
In debugger you can switch the view to e.g. HTML and you should see the whole string, but editing is limited as far as i know to a certain number of charachters.